# Append script tag to the head after page load issue

Tags: javascript, adsense, createelement

I'm trying to append Google AdSense script to the head tag after page gets fully loaded. In brief here's the code that triggers the error

```
var tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.src = "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";
tag.data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxx"; //error gets triggered here
tag.defer="defer";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);
```

In the console I get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

and refers to this line

```
tag.data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxx";
```

How to fix this and if I could make it work this way, will ads appear normally?

Answer (score 0):

try writing it in this way

```
tag['data-ad-client'] = "ca-pub-xxxxxxx";
```

Comment: not added here's the end result ````<script src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" defer=""></script>````

Answer (score 0):

Try using the bracket notation instead..
Square bracket notation allows the use of characters that can't be used with dot notation which is the case here since data-ad-client includes the character '-'

```js
var tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.src = "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";
tag['data-ad-client']="ca-pub-xxxxxxx"; //error gets triggered here
tag.defer="defer";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);
```

Comment: not added here's the end result ````<script src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" defer=""></script>````

Answer (score 0):

Use `tag.setAttribute('data-ad-client') = 'ca-pub-xxxxxx';`.

Or alternatively [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes): `tag.dataset.adClient = 'ca-pub-xxxx';`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, but my advice is to use Async instead of defer

```
    <script>
    var tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";
    tag.setAttribute('data-ad-client', 'ca-pub-xxxxxxx');
    tag.defer=true;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);
    </script>
```

The new adcode has changed a bit

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-1234567890123456" crossorigin="anonymous"</script>
```

You could try this answer
[New Adsense Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68513842/1862521)