# How to lazy load new Google Adsense code using JS

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation, adsense

Google has replaced

`<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js</script>`

with

`<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-1234567890123456" crossorigin="anonymous"</script>`

**ref**: [Google Adsense Announcement](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/10627874)

**Old Adsense Code was like:**

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:350px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
     data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXX"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

**New Adsense Code is like:**

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:350px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
     data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXX"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

**Old JS code to load the Ad after the page load is complete was:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function downloadJSAtOnload() {
        var element = document.createElement("script");
        element.src = "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        }
        if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
        else if (window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
        else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
    </script>
```

As `?client=ca-pub-xxxxxx" crossorigin="anonymous"` is added in script tag of new Ad Code, now what would be the new JS code to load the ads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well This is not really lazy load This is defer loading and not recommended, but here you go

```
<script>
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
    var element = document.createElement("script");
    element.src = "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    element.async = true;
    element.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
    document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

If you are looking for lazy load AdSense check out [Lazy Loading Adsense](https://www.guest.blog/post/12068/lazy-loading-adsense-ads/)

Comment: For reference, does it violate Google Adsense Policy? As we are modifying Ad code.

Comment: No, because when you check the dom of a lazy loaded AdSense adunit, it is the same code as provided by Google. I have used this code on my website for past 6 months, It worked without any issues or warnings from Google.

Comment: Where can I find DOM of lazy loaded Adsense Unit? Clarify please.

Comment: Website link you provided is not accessible!!

Comment: Right click and select Inspect element on an Adsense adunit.
Which link is not working?
I just edited the above script to add async attribute.

Comment: lazy loading adsense link is inaccessible.

Comment: It works for my end, Try to flush dns or try again after restarting router.